# Is there a way to specify which schema the database task "Export Data-tier Application" exports for the other entities besides the tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, schema, export, data-tier-application

I noticed in the Export Data-tier Application database task, you can specify which schema to export data from in regards to tables, but I also want to exclude certain schemas for the other object types too such as views and stored procedures. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to include stored procedures in export data, uncheck the option  to exclude stored procedures from exporting data